# Can I buy a direct upgrade from Lightroom 3.5 to Lightroom 5?

Tags: lightroom, software, upgrade, adobe

Do you know if there is any way to upgrade my current Lightroom 3.5 to newest Lightroom 5?

Comment: Are you asking whether the Lightroom 5 software will import your Lightroom 3 library, or are you asking about whether it’s possible to buy an upgrade from Adobe?

Comment: I've been asking about availability to buy direct upgrade to v.5. 
I found on Adobe website there is and upgrade to v.5 which cost $79.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I just asked Adobe and was told that it is possible, at a cost of approximately $75.00

Comment: That was @kenneth.  I just edited the answer a bit

Answer (score 4):

Edited: It seems that you can upgrade from Lightroom v1.x, v2.x, v3.x and v4.x to v5 for the same price (upgrade and not full software). Last time I checked I haven't found this possibility. Good news for everyone :)

Regarding your **Lightroom software** v3.5, installing Lightroom 5 will not modify your 3.5 installation (you will still be able to launch Lightroom v3.5).

Regarding your **Lightroom catalog** v3.5, Lightroom 5 will create on installation a copy of your catalog v3.5 and "upgrade" it to v5.
Look [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5618943) for more detail.

If you have any doubt, copy your catalog v3.5 somewhere else before installation.

More detail on updating Lightroom from vxxx to v5 [here](http://www.lightroompresets.com/blogs/pretty-presets-blog/8166935-top-5-questions-about-upgrading-to-lightroom-5).

For information, Lightroom 3 and Lightroom 5 aren't using the same Process Version. You should probably read about it so you won't be surprised.

Comment: LR 5 will not change the images at all. Even though it has a newer process version, existing images will remain in the existing process version. You can upgrade the image process version for any images you wish later.

Comment: You are right @cmason.
However, when using an "older" process version, Lightroom seems to be very happy to remind you that your are indeed using an old one. I just wanted Holy Sync not to be afraid of that.

Comment: Do you have any experience using both 3.5 and 5? I mean - Is it worth making the upgrade?

I also consider to switch to current version of the Aperture which cost slisly cheaper than the upgrade for Lightroom v5.

Comment: From my experience, upgrading from v3 to v4 was worth it ! I haven't upgrade to Lightroom v5 as the difference doesn't seems as important. But you will indubitably see a real gain going from v3 to v5.

I have no Aperture experience, so I can't help you on this subject. However, you can look at the tons of comparative reviews between those two major players. There is a war out there, Son !!

Comment: Thank you @Olivier for sharing :)
I wish to avoid LR/Apt war ._.

Comment: The best option for me is the lens correction including option to straighten the images (architecture and interior photography).